# Video not rotating using AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to merge two videos I get after recording using the camera as a UIImagePickerController. I've succeeded with combining the videos into one but I have some problems with the orientation of the videos.

As I've understood it with the UIImagePickerController is that all videos are captured in landscape, this means that the videos recorded in portrait are rotated 90°.

After each recording I add the new video to an array

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:NSDictionary) {
    let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as NSURL
    videos.append(tempImage)
    let pathString = tempImage.relativePath
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
}
```

Then when I want to merge I go through each video and create an instruction and adds the instruction to another array

```
var composition = AVMutableComposition()
let trackVideo:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
let trackAudio:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
var insertTime = kCMTimeZero

for i in 0...(videos.count-1){
    let moviePathUrl = videos[i]
    let sourceAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: moviePathUrl, options: nil)

    let tracks = sourceAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let audios = sourceAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)

    if tracks.count > 0{
        var videoDuration = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, sourceAsset.duration);

        let assetTrack:AVAssetTrack = tracks[0] as AVAssetTrack
        let assetTrackAudio:AVAssetTrack = audios[0] as AVAssetTrack

        trackVideo.insertTimeRange(videoDuration, ofTrack: assetTrack, atTime: insertTime, error: nil)
        trackAudio.insertTimeRange(videoDuration, ofTrack: assetTrackAudio, atTime: insertTime, error: nil)

        //Rotate
        var rotater = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: assetTrack)
        rotater.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform, atTime: insertTime)
        rotater.setOpacity(0.0, atTime: CMTimeAdd(insertTime, sourceAsset.duration))
        instructions.append(rotater)

        //Resize
        var resizer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: assetTrack)
        resizer.setCropRectangle(CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300), atTime: insertTime)
        instructions.append(resizer)

        insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, sourceAsset.duration)

    }
}
```

When I've created all the instructions I add them to the main instruction and create the export session.

```
var instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction();
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, insertTime);

instruction.layerInstructions = instructions;
var mainCompositionInst = AVMutableVideoComposition()
mainCompositionInst.instructions = NSArray(object: instruction)

mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(300, 300);

var exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
exporter.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `trackVideo` in the initializer for your layer Instruction so it will use the `AVMutableCompositionTrack`'s `trackID` rather than the source asset's `trackID`

Update:

You only need one `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction`, so declare it before the loop with the `AVMutableCompositionTrack` as the parameter.  Then on each iteration of the loop, set the necessary properties of the layer instruction (transform, crop rect) for the current video asset you're working with.  You're controlling how the video content in the composition track should be displayed at each insert time.

At the end, place the single layerInstruction in the instructions array, and use that in the video composition.

```
var layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: trackVideo)
for i in 0...(videos.count-1){
   //...your other code here

   layerInstruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform, atTime: insertTime)
   layerInstruction.setCropRectangle(CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300), atTime: insertTime)
}

var instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction();
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, insertTime);

instruction.layerInstructions = NSArray(object: layerInstruction);
var mainCompositionInst = AVMutableVideoComposition()
mainCompositionInst.instructions = NSArray(object: instruction)
```

Comment: Still the same problem, no difference

Comment: Actually, I think you just need one instance of `rotater`.  There's only one video composition track, so you need to declare `rotater` outside the loop, and set the transform to apply at the start time of each new video.  If you're concatenating videos, there's no need to set the opacity to 0 either.  The next one will just show up.

Comment: If I understood you right, I create the rotate using trackVideo right before the loop. Then inside the loop I set the transform just like I did before. This doesn't work either. :/

Comment: I can't find any member "instructions" for AVMutableVideoComposition in Swift 4.

Answer (score 1):

You have two layers. You need to apply the rotation instruction to both layers in the composition. What you are doing here is applying the rotation instruction to only one of them. Get a reference to both elements in the video composition and apply separate instructions to the two layers.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm already doing? I added more of my code to my question

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this simple code,It works for me:

```
  var assetVideoTrack = (sourceAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)).last as! AVAssetTrack

  var compositionVideoTrack = (composition.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)).last as! AVMutableCompositionTrack

  if (assetVideoTrack.playable && compositionVideoTrack.playable) {

       compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = assetVideoTrack.preferredTransform
   }
```