# Merge videos in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I'm using this wonderful tutorial to load 2 videos and merge them in iOS.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

I'd like to adapt this to be able to handle unlimited videos selected by the user, but am struggling.  How do I create an array of AVAsset objects that can then be combined into a single video?

Answer (score 0):

I save each video's MediaURL in an array which I then use to read each video from when I want to merge them. You can see more of it in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627610/video-not-rotating-using-avmutablevideocompositionlayerinstruction)

Note how I handle the insert time after each merge.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy to extend it to any number of videos. All you need is their URL. In the tutorial you mentioned they merge two videos so you know the basics. Just look at this [tutorial](http://blog.peterkim.co/ios-tutorial-how-to-merge-videos-via-avfoundation). It matches exactly your requirement and easy to understand.

You just have to implement `getRandomVideoFileURL` method. Create an array of all video's URL. Pass the index of loop (i) and get the URL.

**UPDATE**: To add instructions, put this part in your loop:

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *videoCompositionInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(time, assetTrack.timeRange.duration);
videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = @[[AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoCompositionTrack]];
[instructions addObject:videoCompositionInstruction];
```

Then, after the loop form `AVMutableVideoComposition` like this:

```
AVMutableVideoComposition *mutableVideoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
mutableVideoComposition.instructions = instructions;
mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = size;
```

Change the variable names as you need, as I don't know which tutorial you are following.

Comment: That's a good article, but the problem is that I'm trying to incorporate LayerInstructions as I go through my loop.  To do so, it looks like you need AVMutableVideoComposition objects which that article does not use.  Basically, I need to figure out how merge the 2 articles together.